# VSCode extension for identifying dead typescript code

Tags: software-development, visual-studio-code, typescript

VSCode already detects dead code using eslint, but this only tells me if

- an import is unused
- code is being executed after a return
- non-exported functions are unused

I'm looking for a tool that I can feed my typescript code into and have it tell me

- exported functions that are not used anywhere within the opened project

Anyone have a recommendation for this?